# Determine modifier key state without an InputEvent object in Java

Tags: java, keyboard, awt

I need to determine the current state of the Shift key, but at the time I need the state I don't have an `InputEvent` object around.  I need something like [`java.awt.Toolkit.getLockingKeyState(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getLockingKeyState(int)) that works for Shift, not just the locking keys like `VK_CAPS_LOCK`.  Is there a way I can do this without listening to input events and storing the for later when I need to check the state?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question.  The implementation I work with uses an InputEvent/KeyListener but it means we have a hack to determine whether shift is down or not that does not work if you have another application focused, press shift, then move to our application window.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to get the status of the Shift key if you don't have an Event in hand. Even  java.awt.Toolkit.getLockingKeyState(int) uses native code to get its information. I'm sure you could devise your own event tracker/store, etc, but just in case, here is a small method that could be usefull. You must provide it with an AWT Component that has the focus.

```
public static boolean isShiftDown(Component c) throws AWTException {
    final List<Boolean> res = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    final KeyListener listener = new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            res.add(e.isShiftDown());
        }
    };
    c.addKeyListener(listener);
    new Robot().keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    try {Thread.sleep(50);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    c.removeKeyListener(listener);
    if (res.size() > 0)
        return res.get(0);
    throw new AWTException("Could not get shift key status.");
}
```